# Can I safely change the OU for an AD DC? What about for a Shared Exchange Mailbox?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, exchange-2013, organizational-unit

Running Windows Server 2012 R2 Active Directory Domain with Exchange Server 2013 CU13

I initially set up my Domain with a very basic structure, and just used the built-in default `Users` and `Computers` containers at the root of the domain.

I have since started organizing my Domain into OUs and moving everything around.

This might be a silly paranoid question but I just want to make sure there are no unforseen consequences.

Other than the obvious GPO implications, do I have to worry at all about any possible problems if I change the OU of:

1. Domain Controllers?  Right now they are all in the root `Computers` container
2. Exchange Servers? Also in the root `Computers` container
3. Shared Exchange Mailboxes?  Right now all shared mailboxes are in the root `Users` container.  There is an option to assign a Shared Mailbox to an OU in Exchange Server 2013 web-based control panel, but there doesn't seem to be any way to change the OU once the mailbox is created from within the web-config.  I don't know if this is trying to tell me that they *shouldn't* be changed or if it is just Microsoft overlooking a UI feature, or just me being blind.

Comment: `Domain Controllers? Right now they are all in the root Computers OU.` - Computers is a container, not an OU. You can move them anywhere you want but the Domain Controllers by default are in the Domain Controllers OU. `Exchange Servers? Also in the root Computers OU.` - You can move them anywhere you want, other than the Domain Controllers OU. To clarify: The Computers and Users nodes/folders/objects are **not** OU's, they are containers. Understanding the difference is crucial. You can link a GPO to an OU but not to a container.

Comment: Yes, you're right, an OU is a specific *kind* of container.  I'm not sure how important it is to understand that they are different besides the fact that you can't link GPO.  An OU is a custom container, whereas `Users` and `Computers` are generic containers created by default.  Thanks for your answers: now what about shared mailboxes?